# Hyperledger Fabric 2.0.1 - filelock and Fabcar

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have the following error -

```
opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer # peer node pause -c mychannel

Error: as another peer node command is executing, wait for that command to complete
 its execution or terminate it before retrying: lock 
is already acquired on file /var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/fileLock
Usage:
  peer node pause [flags]
Flags:
  -c, --channelID string   Channel to pause.
  -h, --help               help for pause
```

```
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer # ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      1:49 peer node start
  519 root      0:00 sh
  586 root      0:00 ps
```

I just started fabcar using the script. I exec -it into the docker container to run this command. I have node 12.18.3 installed on the main EC2.

I have these containers running -

```
 docker ps --format "{{.ID}}/{{.Names}}"
14ccb4493e4c/dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar_1-2939b5f219f516bc94df2253438bad440d6a91432f6b5bbd17ef05d2228766e8
9e5943412e17/dev-peer0.org2.example.com-fabcar_1-2939b5f219f516bc94df2253438bad440d6a91432f6b5bbd17ef05d2228766e8
5f94d6a7eeca/peer0.org2.example.com
83bf6641c159/peer0.org1.example.com
9e24ffd09351/couchdb1
4e5ae5836927/orderer.example.com
ca536a89512c/couchdb0
f52c919a12f2/ca_org1
6c1883daba83/ca_org2
8c2ba199ce33/ca_orderer
```

I am unsure how to debug this. Can anyone assist?

Trevor

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the actual command help `peer node pause --help`:

```
$ peer node pause --help
Pauses a channel on the peer. When the command is executed, the peer must be offline. When the peer starts after pause, it will not receive blocks for the paused channel.

Usage:
  peer node pause [flags]

Flags:
  -c, --channelID string   Channel to pause.
  -h, --help               help for pause
```

you'll see you first need to stop the peer and then issue the command. Since you are running in docker you would need to modify the start up command to hijack the startup process to stop the channel before relaunching the peer. You could modify the compose file temporarily to do this for you.